# Stop the while loop if enter the negative number

Tags: python, while-loop, break

I've started with learning Python and now I am stuck with the WHILE loop, so if you could give me some advice, I would appreciate it.

So, this is my code and what I need is to stop the whole code if I enter the negative number and to print ("Wrong entry"), but my code, on entering the negative number, still passes and prints me also ("Avg price:").
I would like not to print ("Avg price is: ") when I enter e.g. (2,3,6, -12) - only to print ("Wrong entry"). I now that my last print is within WHILE loop, but I am trying to find the solutions :)
Probably, there is easier solution for this, but as I said I am the newbie and still learning
Thank you in advance.

```
price= int(input("Enter the price: "))

price_list=[]

while price!= 0:
    price_list.append(price)
    if price< 0:
       print("Wrong entry")
       break
    price=int(input())

    price_sum= sum(price_list)
print(f"Avg price is: {price_sum / len(price_list)}")
```

Comment: Because average price is calculated outside the loop. It doesn't matter if you input positive or negative number

Comment: Your code above works as you hope it to work. The while loop stops when entering a negative number. But rest of code is run as well.

Comment: There should be a proper condition to stop the while loop. Otherwise you will keep entering values forever. If I enter 0, the loop would stop, but then I have to re-enter the previous correct values again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a while/else loop produces your desired behaviour.

- The code in the else doesn't run if the break in the while loop is encountered

**Code**

```
price= int(input("Enter the price: "))

price_list=[]

while price!= 0:
    price_list.append(price)
    if price< 0:
       print("Wrong entry")
       break
    price=int(input())

    price_sum= sum(price_list)
else:
    print(f"Avg price is: {price_sum / len(price_list)}")
```

Comment: Yes, this ELSE is what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because it is outside the loop, it will always run.

So try this:

```
price= int(input("Enter the price: "))

price_list=[]

while price != 0:
    if price< 0:
       print("Wrong entry")
       break
    price_list.append(price)
    price=int(input())            
    price_sum= sum(price_list)
if price > 0:
    print(f"Avg price is: {price_sum / len(price_list)}")
```

Comment: If you give negative number after any positive number, this approach doesn't work. It will print because there is items in price_lis arrayt.

Comment: @ex4 Misread the question, edited my answer and should work now

Comment: It should return Avg price if I entered all positive prices and 0  is the break for the loop. It does not return Avg price for the positive numbers

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to run rest of code when getting negative number, you can do something like this:

```
price= int(input("Enter the price: "))
ok = True
price_list=[]

while price!= 0:
    price_list.append(price)
    if price< 0:
       print("Wrong entry")
       ok = False
       break
    price=int(input())
if ok:
    price_sum= sum(price_list)
    print(f"Avg price is: {price_sum / len(price_list)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here. You can include the check in the while guard, like this `while price > 0` **or** you can use the keyword `break` and add an if guard inside the loop, like this

```
if price < 0:
    break
```

Since the first time you input the price it is outside the loop, the best course would be to add the guard to the while loop, so that it gets skipped in case first input is negative.

Comment: `price > 0` means that price can't be zero, so `price != 0` is redundant

Answer (score 0):

You are doing procedural programming here. You `print` statement it outside the loop. Also, there is no control statement checking the statement. So regardless of the input, print statement is executed.

Since any non empty list is a truth value, you can check if the list is empty or it contains some elements

```
price= int(input("Enter the price: "))

price_list=[]

while price!= 0:
    
    if price< 0:
       print("Wrong entry")
       break
    price_list.append(price)
    price=int(input())
if price_list:
    price_sum= sum(price_list)
    print(f"Avg price is: {price_sum / len(price_list)}")
```